# Jquery on default values

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, how can I change the color of these elements to red if the textboxes contain defaultvalues and the 'isrequired' value is "Yes"?

```
<input type="text" value="Name" isrequired="Yes">
<input type="text" value="Address" isrequired="No">
<input type="text" value="Age" isrequired="Yes">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your input html to add an extra data-* attribute which store defult value

```
<input type="text" value="Name" data-default="Name" isrequired="Yes">
<input type="text" value="Address" data-default="Address" isrequired="No">
<input type="text" value="Age" data-default="Age" isrequired="Yes">
```

Jquery

```
$('input[isrequired=Yes]').each(function(){
if($(this).val()==$(this).data("default"))
{$(this).css('color', 'red');}
})
```

---

**Update** : With using defaultvalue property which is very new to me

```
$('input[isrequired=Yes]').each(function(){
  if (this.value == this.defaultValue) {$(this).css('color', 'red'); }

});
```

Much better ,cleaner.

Comment: do you mean 
    if($(this).val()==$(this).data("data-default")) it worked when I changed "value" to "data-default"

Comment: Or if($(this).val()==$(this).attr("data-default"))

Comment: No extra attribute is required thanks to the `defaultValue` property. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11069015/154877) for an example.

Comment: Only this one worked:  if($(this).val()==$(this).attr("data-default"))

Answer (score 1):

The following will change the text field text red if the value is the default value as the user types.

**JavaScript:** (requires jQuery)

```
$('input[type=text][isrequired=Yes]').on("change", function(){
  if ($(this).val() == this.defaultValue) { $(this).addClass("req"); }
  else { $(this).removeClass("req"); }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.req { color:red }
```

Comment: $(this).defaultValue is undefined so use this.defaultValue

Comment: @undefined: Ahh, habit. Fixed.